# Using Multiple identical sensors - Beginner

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, pressure

I'm trying to make an interactive installation where I have 6 pressure pads that each control an Air Fan. The pressure sensors ideally will be on chairs.

I would like the changes in pressure to change the speed of the Air Fans.

What is the easiest way for me to do this? Can I do it with just an Arduino?

I haven't bought anything yet as I'm assessing what the best route is.

Comment: If you have selected the pressure sensor, please provide details about it -- the type/model affects how this question could be answered.

Comment: well i'm not entirely sure what's best but I was thinking just a PM1?

Comment: When you say PM1, do you mean a pressure pad, something like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/defender-security/pm1-pk/pressure-mat-stair-595x170mm/dp/1146761)?

Comment: yeah that's what i was thinking

Comment: In order to better focus your question and generate useful answers, I suggest you edit your question and include that information.   Try to make your question Arduino-specific, and show what you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes one Arduino have enough in and out-put to make your project fly.

The sensor that would detect pressure sensor is called "Force Sensitive Resistor".

Example: http://www.ladyada.net/make/midisense/forcesensors.html

They need some amplifier circuitry that could adapt the sensors low output signal to an Arduino analog input.

And to make six digital output that uses PWM to control the FAN's is also quite straight forward. but may also be subject to some driver circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this](https://www.aventics.com/de/en/pneumatics-shop/series-pm1-pgr.256289) kind of sensor:

The sensor is a simple microswitch with mechanical pressure switching point, which means your Arduino just needs to monitor 6 digital inputs. That is entirely possible.

The sensors would have one side connected to ground, and the other to a GPIO pin on the Arduino, with a pull-up resistor to 5V. Your code should just check each of the 6 GPIO inputs. If the pressure sensor is tripped, the input would be `LOW`, otherwise `HIGH`.

Comment: This indicate "I would like the changes in pressure to change the speed of the Air Fans." that the OP is asking for an analog answer.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the easiest way for me to do this?

you have to figure out how those sensors output their pressure measurements. if it is analog, you will need 6 analog pins, or have to a way to mux 6 analog inputs.

if it is digital, you will have to figure out how - 6 parallel output or 6 serial output; 6 GPIO digital or 6 numerical digital, ......

basically, do your homework first so others can help you help you.